# Functions Question

Tags: functions

I am not sure how to solve the question below, if anyone could help me with it I would much appreciate it.

> The functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are given by:
>   $$f(x) = \frac{x+1}{3}$$
>   $$g(x) = 3x + 2$$
>   Determine the functions $(g \circ f)(x)$ and the function $(f \circ g)(x)$.

Comment: Woops, forgot the other \$ after \$(f \circ g)(x). You might want to add one before the "." I can't re-edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I will help you with the first question.

This is asking for $g(f(x))$. What is $f(x)$? It's just $ (x+1)/3 $. Now plug that value into g. We get $ 3 * (x + 1) / 3 + 2 $ which simplifies to x + 3.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write this would be:

> Determine $g(f(x))$ and $f(g(x))$.

To do this, rewrite the functions as one in terms of the other.
If $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{3}$ and $g(x) = 3x + 2$, then:
$$f(g(x)) = f({\small 3x + 2}) = \frac{(3x+2)+1}{3} = \frac{3x+3}{3} = \frac{3(x+1)}{3} = \boxed{x+1}$$
$$g(f(x)) = g({\small\frac{x+1}{3}}) = 3\Big(\frac{x+1}{3}\Big)+2 = (x+1)+2 =  \boxed{x + 3}$$

Comment: Commutative by accident.

Comment: Oops... Updated my answer to omit the stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

f o g = (3x+2 + 1)/3   ....   gof = 3((x + 1)/3) + 2...
To understand this properly see C. Sidney's notation for functions and their composites

Comment: Find Ephraim's error

Comment: I have to ask... who was this comment supposed to be to?